# QuerySelector on Class Buttons from another group of buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I trying to use below command: I would like to select a group of buttons from another bigger group of buttons

```
var btns = document.querySelector('(button[class=QualityIntbtn]):not([id=reset]):not([id=submit])');
```

Is it right ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `.querySelectorAll()` instead to select plus that one element and adjust your selector a little like :

```
document.querySelectorAll('button.QualityIntbtn:not(#reset):not(#submit)')
```

**Working snippet :**

```js
var btns = document.querySelectorAll('button.QualityIntbtn:not(#reset):not(#submit)');

console.log(btns.length);
```

```html
<button class="QualityIntbtn" id="reset">Reset</button>
<button class="QualityIntbtn" id="test1">test 1</button>
<button class="QualityIntbtn" id="test2">test 2</button>
<button class="QualityIntbtn" id="submit">Submit</button>
<button class="QualityIntbtn" id="test3">test 3</button>
```